# where's the error of this calculation?

Tags: expectation, exponential-distribution

Let $X=2e^{-2\theta}$, ask to calculate $E[X^2]$. Here's the right way to calculate it
$$E[X^2]=var[X]+(E[X])^2={1\over 2^2} + ({1\over 2})^2={1\over 2}$$
but if I do it in another way
$$E[X^2]=E[(2e^{-2\theta})^2] = E[4e^{-4\theta}]= {1\over 4}$$
Then it ends up $1\over 4$, what's wrong with the second calculation?

Comment: You can't just square the distribution function of $X$ and think that that's the distribution function for $X^2$. Try it with a uniform variable on $[0,1]$ and see how that's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
E[X^2] = \int_0^{\infty} x^2 2e^{-2x} dx = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
$X=2e^{-2x}$ is confusing, since $X$ is a function that has the distribution $2e^-2x$.

Comment: I see, I squared the distribution instead of the random variable, that's where the error is.

Comment: Right, it might be useful to note that $P(a \leq X\leq b) = \int_a^b 2e^{-2x}$, but not $X=2e^{-2x}$.